# Repeater with dynamic UC

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a formular with dynamic data and UC.

my ascx file looks like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rMyData" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnRepeaterItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelAdditional" runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the cs file:

```
public partial class MyFormular
{

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PrepareList();
                DataBind();
            }
        }

        private void PrepareList()
        {
            rMyData.DataSource = GetData();
            rMyData.DataBind();
        }

        protected void OnRepeaterItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RepeaterItem repeaterItem = e.Item;
            Panel panel = (Panel)repeaterItem.FindControl("panelAdditional");
            if (panel != null)
            {
                var datarow= (Data)repeaterItem.DataItem;

                if (datarow!= null)
                {
                    panel.Controls.Clear();

                    MyUC ctrl;
                    ctrl = (MyUC)Page.LoadControl("~/MyUC.ascx");
                    ctrl.Enabled = true;
                    ctrl.DataRow = datarow;
                    panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void SaveNewsletterSubscription(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

My problem is, it doesn't show my UC.
If I put my PrepareList() and DataBind() outside of the PostBack, it works perfectly fine and shows my UC. But after I press the save Button, it reloads the page and rebind my repeater. So I lost everything in the UC.
Why does it only show my UC if I rebind it in every pageload?
I hope the I posted enough information.

Comment: Have you tried changing your logic: if (IsPostback) { /* save changed values before they are overwritten */ }

Comment: You should bind outside the `IsPostBack` check. And what do you mean by "lost everything". Because if I test a simple scenario it works just fine.

Comment: The problem is. If I bind it outside the if(IsPostBack) it rebind my recreate my UC and every checkbox, textfield... in it, and the UC will be empty afterwards.
Hm I can try it. But it's not easy, to save the generated data from a dynamic generated UC in the parent.